# How do I create an alarm clock like Alertmanager?

Tags: java, android

The alarm clock must start by itself, even if the app has been closed and the smartphone restarts.
Is there a safe way to program such an alarm clock?

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent startServicePendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getService(context,0,startServiceIntent,0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(alarmManager != null)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() 
                    + 1000 * 60,1000 * 30,startServicePendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  easily but you need  add some Property to your app like :
1-set first method for set alarm
2-save and handle value for alarm (Room ، Sql or etc)  // if you want make loop alarm
3-use broadcastreceiver for two reason(set notification or handle background and close app or restart or somethings like that)
4- some custom method for better handle data streaming in app

i hope this link will can help you
[link refrences](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEMTQYxBp7k7mC1DvjnVjFpMPJ_5wbKM/view)
have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!
Can you give me a quick example of this?

Comment: you're welcome. This example can meet all your needs    [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEMTQYxBp7k7mC1DvjnVjFpMPJ_5wbKM/view?usp=drivesdk)